# Should my function be in /mixins or /plugins?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

If I have an external package that I'm using, for instance, [`vue-js-modal`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-modal). And I import it in `/plugins/vue-js-modal.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'

Vue.use(VModal)
```

Now let's say I have a function that uses `vue-js-modal` that I want to use in a bunch of different components below:

```
function showHideModal(showModalName = null, hideModalName = null) {
    if (hideModalName) {
        this.$modal.hide(hideModalName)
    }
    if (showModalName) {
        this.$modal.show(showModalName)
    }
}
```

Should this function be stored in `/plugins/vue-js-modal.js` or should it be put into it's own `/mixins/showHideModal.js` file? Which is more appropriate here and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) document in Nuxt.js website:

> Nuxt.js allows you to define JavaScript plugins to be run before instantiating the root Vue.js Application. This is especially helpful when using Vue libraries, external modules or your own plugins.

So if you want to use external modules it's better to have them stored/initiated in plugins, Whereas if you want to have reusable functions for components, you use Mixins which then "Mix" the function and the component together.

Read more about mixins [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).